# Приостановка и возобновление Activity

Tags: android

У меня несколько активити, каждое из них пользователь заполняет определенной информацией. Как сделать так, чтобы при сворачивании приложения данные с активити не удалялись и пользователю приходилось начинать заполнять все сначала, а чтобы при возобновлении пользователь мог спокойно продолжить заполнять активити с того места, где остановился?

Comment: приложение должно работать так, как вам нужно поумолчанию, без каких-либо дополнительных действий. Раз оно так не работает, значит вы сделали что-то, что заставляет его работать не так.

Comment: Верно было подмечено ;)

Comment: обычно это классика жанра - переопределить метод (тот же onCreate) и забыть вызвать super метод.

Answer (score 3):

Все хорошо описано (с примерами) в [документации](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html). Если кратко, то андроид вызывает метод `onSaveInstanceState` и передает bundle. В нем нужно сохранить все нужные Вам данные. Когда нужно восстановить данные, андроди дергает метод `onRestoreInstanceState` и передает туда этот же bundle (также этот бандл передается и в `onCreate`). Используя его, можно восстановить нужные данные.

А вот обычные контролы сами восстанавливаются, если заданы id и ничего лишнего не дописано.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, +1 к карме)

Comment: "А вот обычные контролы сами восстанавливаются, если заданы id" что Вы имеет ввиду ? Какие обычные контролы ?

Comment: например, поле ввода или check box.

Answer (score 2):

Сохраняйте состояние активити. Потом восстанавливайте. Для этого надо:

перекрыть метод `onSaveInstanceState`

```
@Override  
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {  
    // что надо сохранить, вставляем в outState  
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);  
}
```

дописать `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ваш код создания активити
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      // восстанавливаем что надо из savedInstanceState
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, +1 к карме)